# Camel cxf webservice - problem with getting Response

Tags: web-services, ssl, apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse

I encounter problem with Apache Camel.
I did two SOAP WebServices. First (i will call it A ) is a standard Proxy which calling WebServices B which do all job (getting data from Datebase, parsing response etc.).

It works very well as i expected. Im sending data to the A by SoapUI, A is sending request to B, B is getting data from database, parsing response, sending it to A, A is sending response to Soap UI. Perfect... until everything is working on http.

When i turn on ssl on JbossFuse where WebService A is deployed i'am  able to send request by SoapUI to Webservice A, A is sending request to B, B is sending response, A is getting responce ( i see it in log ), and ... nothing more happen. SoapUI getting SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out.

It's look like WebService  A doesn't know where should send response. Nothing especially happened in logs, 0 exceptions. Probably i forgot about one thing and i don't know what. 
Jboss which i use is old one  6.1.0.redhat-379.

Have someone any ideas what can i do/what can i check which help me solve my problem?

Comment: Are you able to fetch the wsdl with the https url for Service A?

Comment: Of course, im able to get wsdl from https. I think problem is in calling webservice B, when i turning off  calling B (just commenting it in code)  im getting responce from A to SoapUI. Its look like calling B cause override SOAP headers (or somethink in adress) of A and A isn't able to send response. I tried a lot of things and everytink ends same.

Comment: service B also https ? and deployed in same server?

Comment: B is http, and its located on separated server. I test it localy on two Jboss Fuse instances. Serwer where A is deployed with ssl turned on,  and server B without ssl, and this case is also visible.

Comment: communication between http -> https endpoint often requires the certificate to be installed correctly in keystore , Do you see any PKIX error anywhere ?

Comment: No. I don't have error anywhere, i even looked into system logs and everywhere was all ok. As i said it's look like my version of JbossFuse have bug, where calling webservice B (from blueprint ) override headers of Webservice A. 
I did workaround and now work everything works as i expected. Thx for interest of my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not solution, but it's workaround of my problem.
I just did simple Ws Client in Webservice A which connect to Webservice B. Then instead of calling endpoint of WS B from blueprint, i call Bean with WS Client.